# Flask: Preferred way to manipulate view arguments?

Tags: python, rest, sqlalchemy, flask

I'm creating REST API with Flask & have a question related to manipulating the arguments of the view questions. I have currently two resources, "Survey" and "SurveyStep", accessible through:

```
/surveys
/survey/*survey-id*/steps/*step-id*
```

Since I'll be using the Survey resource for each request, I want it to be fetched automatically (SQLAlchemy) before each request.

Currently I found 3 ways to do this:

1) Write a URL converter, as described in (http://corbinsimpson.com/entries/be-prepared.html)

2) Use @....before_request, adding things to the request.view_args manually

3) Use @....before_request, adding it to the flask.g object

I first tried 1), which has the issue that the alchemy objects do not belong to the session, and in case of lazy relationships they need to be added first.

2) seems "dirty", as your functions get arguments that aren't really visibly declared

3) is what I'm using now, it makes the view arguments not needed in the functions itself, but it solves the session issue & it's a bit more visible than 2.

Any thoughts, caveats, improvements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `g` is a good solution for a system which **always** needs the `Survey` object.

For a mixed context I would do a simple `decorator` loading the appropriate `Survey` object and passing it to the decorated function (updating `kwargs` for example) or something like that. Even putting the object in `g`, but only for that function.

Like:

```
@app.route(...)
@load_survey
def do_something(....):
  ...
```

Comment: Ha, I keep forgetting decorators :-). Thanks, this is nice & clean.